# Is the maximal order of a number field monogenic with GP-Pari

Tags: nt.number-theory

For my thesis, I need to study hundreds of maximal orders. So hand computations are unwelcome!!!

I would like to know if there is a way to prove that the maximal order of a number field is monogenic by using GP-Pari.

I checked in the documentation but I did not find that.

Does anyone have an idea how to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not try the PARI mailing list?

Comment: http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/lists-index.html

Comment: Have you looked at this related question? http://mathoverflow.net/questions/21267/which-number-fields-are-monogenic-and-related-questions