# Characterize the set of roots of cubics with certain properties

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, norms

Let $P(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be an irreducible polynomial of degree $3$. Suppose that $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3$ are roots of $P(x)$. For what such $P(x)$ is it the case that the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha_1]$ is $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha_1]$.

Also, let $p$ be a prime, and consider $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha_1]/(p)$. Let 
$$\text {Nm}(x + y\alpha_1 + z\alpha_1^2) = \prod_{i\le 3}(x + y\alpha_i + z\alpha_i^2)$$

For what primes $p$ is it the case that if $\text{Nm}(x + y\alpha_1 + z\alpha_1^2) = 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha_1]/(p)$, then $p|x, y, z$?

I will also will be fine with a method for generating such polynomials and primes.

Comment: I don't think there's a simple answer to the first question. Chapter 7.3 of Alaca and Williams, Introductory Algebraic Number Theory, will give you some idea of the complications involved.

Comment: I am also fine with a method for generating such polynomials and primes, as seen in my new edit.

Comment: In that case, if $m$ is squarefree, and $m^2\not\equiv1\pmod9$, then the ring of integers in ${\bf Q}(\root3\of m)$ is ${\bf Z}[\root3\of m]$.

Comment: Is there any good method for testing whether a polynomial has this property, or whether it satisfies the second property?

Comment: Have you gone through Chapter 7.3 of Alaca and Williams yet?

Comment: I don't have that book.

Comment: Pity, that. It's a good book to have, if you are interested in this sort of question. Are there any libraries where you live?

Comment: You may also want to look at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/21267/which-number-fields-are-monogenic-and-related-questions