# Criterion for Dedekind domains

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let $m(x)$ be a monic irreducible polynomial in $Z[x]$. Is there any criterion for the quotient ring $Z[x]/(m(x))$ to be Dedekind domain ?

Thanks.

Comment: It is delicate to characterize when $\mathbf{Z}[x]/(x^n-a)$ is integrally closed if $x^n-a$ irreducible over $\mathbf{Q}$ (e.g., for prime $p$, $\mathbf{Z}[2^{1/p}]$ is integrally closed if and only if ${\rm{ord}}_p(2^p-2) = 1$, for which $p=1093, 3511$ are the known counterexamples), so it is unlikely that there is a useful general sufficient criterion beyond the obvious one of $m$ being an Eisenstein-translate at every prime dividing its discriminant. See Corollary 3.4, Examples 3.5-3.6, Theorem 5.1, and Theorem 5.3 of http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/integersradical.pdf

Comment: Are you asking for some kind of general reason, or to check this in concrete cases? For example, if this is coming up in a *course* then a handy sufficient condition is if the discriminant of $m(x)$ is squarefree. In nature that criterion often doesn't apply. A buzzword that you can use to find more information on this is "monogenic ring of integers". For example, googling that term will lead you to the page http://mathoverflow.net/questions/21267/which-number-fields-are-monogenic-and-related-questions.

Comment: @KConrad: I will look at it. Thanks.